# Use of model and some tools from QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

(repost)

This is what I want to do...

Data:
-raster images with 4 bands (green,red,red-edge and NIR),there are like 30 folders with one zone per folder and the images where taken 3 periods of time.
-List of chlorophyll indices that I need to obtain.

Procedure:
1. I have to merge the images because the UAV separate them.
2. Calculate the chlorophyll indices with raster calculator.
3. another step (pending).
4. another step (pending).

How you guys see,there are multiple procedures that are repeated so I need to automatize them, my first option is use the model tool of QGIS but I can't find the way to calculate the chlorophyll indices with this model.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, please take the tour https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Can you post separate questions instead of combining your questions about a. mosaicing rasters and b. calculating indexes into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Under the 'raster' tab there is a suite of GDAL tools (Geospatial Data Abstraction Library). See this link: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_gdaltools.html
and here:
https://gdal.org/

While I cant go into specifics without more information from your question, I have used GDAL for many different routines, ie merge, clipping, indexing etc.

I recommend you start there and put some of the tools together.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, please take the [tour] to have a clear understanding on to answer Questions. Ask for more clarification in comments and not in the answer.

Comment: I found the raster calculator as a GDAL tool in the algorithms of the model, but I dont know how put my raster bands there for calculate my vegetation indexes automatically.

Comment: @Shiko Thanks for taking the high ground there. I appreciate your sentiment and I am familiar with the process, but I didn't have the privilege to add a comment at the time - only to use the answer function. This is a real oversight on behalf of the site and leads to receiving well meaning comments as your 'dont do that' when folk like me are only trying to help and have no other option available to post. Perhaps you shouldn't be as quick to judge negatively and pass comment next time? The situation was not as clear as you thought...

Comment: @JavierPadilla C'mon Javier, give a full description of what you want to do. Include a pipeline of the work (either ideal or work thus far) and give a full description of your expected output. Also a good idea to update your question with some tried and failed information. Otherwise, we are just guessing at every element of this process. If you cant give more info - I cant give an answer sorry.